# Mongoose does not throw error when validate in schema matches false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I created custom generic validation functions for most common scenarios in my application, for example email validation, phone number validation and date/time validation.

validation of time (HH:MM format):

```
    validateTime: (time) => {
        return [new RegExp(HHMM_TIME_FORMAT).test(time), 'Wrong time format. Expected hh:mm']
    }
```

Usage in model:

```
...
        visitHourStart: {
            type: String,
            validate: modelValidator.validateTime
        }
...
```

Given `VisitHourStart` value: `x08:30x`,
`validateTime` returns `false` - this is good behavior, but it does not throw error with given message. Document is being saved to database with wrong time.

How to tell my model to throw an error on unsuccessful validation?

**EDIT1:**
Changing `validate: modelValidator.validateTime` to

```
validate: {
    validator: time => new RegExp(HHMM_TIME_FORMAT).test(time),
    message: 'Wrong time format. Expected hh:mm'
}
```

inside schema does not work, still no error getting thrown and document is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validate` parameter expects an object representing [Custom Validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators) like below:

```
visitHourStart: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
        validator: time => new RegExp(HHMM_TIME_FORMAT).test(time),
        message: 'Wrong time format. Expected hh:mm'
    }
}
```

you can also specify `RegExp` type directly instead of arrow function:

```
visitHourStart: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
        validator: new RegExp(HHMM_TIME_FORMAT),
        message: 'Wrong time format. Expected hh:mm'
    }
}
```

EDIT: in your example you're passing an arrow function which returns an array while Mongoose expects an array to be specified directly like below:

```
validate: [
    new RegExp(HHMM_TIME_FORMAT),
    'Wrong time format. Expected hh:mm'
]
```

I've tested all the three above ways and the error gets thrown each time

Comment: still no error thrown and record gets added to database, unfortunately

Comment: @mickl I thought of the same but one can define the validator like OP has posted. [Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate)

Comment: @ambianBeing thanks for this remark. The thing is that this syntax is a bit different than the one used by OP

Comment: @janlan could you also show how you're saving your doc ? I've tried simple `.save()` and all the ways described in my answer are throwing an error

Comment: @mickl Saw the edit, that might be it. Cool! Wondering if simply returning an array with correct format would be breaking this, OP is doing the same isn't it. Also would want see how documents are being stored.

Comment: @ambianBeing there's a difference between an `array` and `function returning an array`. I guess mongoose doesn't expect any function so the framework isn't invoking that function and thus his validator wasn't getting applied. Now it works :)